# Phone Gap build: “ERROR: Start Page at 'www/index.html' was not found”

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-build

I get this error when I've created a zip file for upload on phonegap build. Here is what I've found so far:

1. Moving the files to a subfolder \www\ dosn't work. This gives "Error - No index.html found - You can fix this here"
2. Copying the files to a subfolder \www\ does work. So as long as the files are duplicated bewtween the folders \www\ and \ it works.

My folder structure:

```
\index.html
\config.xml
\icon.png
\content\*.css
\content\images\*.png
\Scripts\*.js
\CustomScripts\*.js
```

And by moving/duplicating I mean this:

```
\www\index.html
\www\content\*.css
\www\content\images\*.png
\www\Scripts\*.js
\www\CustomScripts\*.js
```

Is this the only way to make it work? The duplication seems really bad in terms of app size. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I'd managed to give the root index file the name of Index.html (while the copy was lowercase.)

Answer (score 1):

This happens by default because of file structure.

Easy fix is to open your project in the finder. Drag the `www` file down to the xcode as shown below.

[image: visual]

Answer (score 0):

That is a bit odd.
My first temporary solution is to put an index.html with a redirect tag like so...

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=cordova-app-hello-world-3.3.0-01af7dc\www\index.html" />
```

but it's likely better to just trast the bogus structure there.
I think you need the config.xml and that's about it.

Answer (score -2):

please follow below link

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/app-overview

and it says

**Preparing the Assets**

PhoneGap Build only requires the assets of your application. This is essentially your www directory which contains your html, css, images, js files, etc.

PhoneGap Build will most likely fail to compile your application if native files are uploaded (.h, .m, .java, etc).

Comment: This is not even relevant to the question, sorry.